# moved web form does not load

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I'm a newbie at asp.net and I have asp.net application with nested master pages. (.Net 3.5) I had a web form at root directory and I moved it a folder which I created under root. From this point I started to get "cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory" error while that web form loading. I digged on web and I tried prefixes "~", "/", "../" but I'm nowhere. my code as follows.

```
<li>
     <a href=Staff/New_Staff.aspx">Add New Staff</a>
</li>
```

I tried to create one more web form under "Staff" directory, but this form also generates same error while loading. Appreciate for help.

Comment: Why not use an `asp:Hyperlink` and an application root relative URL like `~/Staff/New_Staff.aspx`?

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you are using double code in href. it should be like this depending on your folder structure.

```
 <a href="Staff/New_Staff.aspx">Add New Staff</a>
```

And
For anyone who has found this thread, addressing relative paths has always created arguments over what is correct or not.

Depending on where you use the path to be addressed, it will depend on how you address the path.

Generally :

. and ./ do the same thing, however you wouldn't use . with a file name. Otherwise you will have the browser requesting .filename.ext as a file from the server. The proper method would be  ./filename.ext.

../ addresses the path up one level from the current folder. If you were in the path /cheese/crackers/yummy.html, and your link code asked for ../butter/spread.html in the document yummy.html, then you would be addressing the path /cheese/butter/spread.html, as far as the server was concerned.

/ will always address the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Web Form, we normally use ***HyperLink*** server control to create URL as *mason* said.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Staff/New_Staff.aspx" Text="Add New Staff"/>
```

If you do not want use it, you can manually prepend with `<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>`.

```
<a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>Staff/New_Staff.aspx">Add New Staff</a>
```